# How to display Loading Screen using Go Router ,Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Does anyone know how to show a loading dialog or screen using Go router
i have to call an api service in order to get the route path so i ahve to show a progress bar in a dialog how can. i achieve that using go router

Answer (score 0):

You could use the root of the router as Loading-Page where you can fetch data from an API and display a Progress-Indicator in the meantime. When finished, you can navigate to your main-page.

Comment: Can you give me an example , that would be so helpful :)

Answer (score -1):

[Asynchronous functions](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await), like calling a **URL** in the web, an **online image** reference, or calling an API, allow you to set specific functions that track the **Request status** and **Response**.

Here's a simple example on how to call a URL with Dart (Flutter):

```
//You'll need this import for making HTTP request
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future String fetchData(String url) async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    // Check if the call to the server was successful
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If server returns an OK response
      return response.body;
    } else {
      return 'Failed to load data from the server';
    }
}
```

if you use a **Future**, you can set a **FutureBuilder**, which changes accordingly if you have or have not the expected response.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
future: _myFuture,
builder: (context,snapshot){
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
   // The connection is awaiting for the response
   return MyLoadingWidget();
} else if (snapshot.hasError) {
   // There was an error on the request
} else {
   // There was a return message, so we use it accordingly
   // The response is stored on the snapshot.data 
   return buildMyWidget( snapshot.data);
}
```

Another way to set a Future callback is to literally call it like this:

```
_myFuture.then(/* code that executes after we get a response */);
```

The cons of this last method, are that you need to do a manual validation of the response, check if there was an error in the call, and if the service response is valid or not.

Comment: I tried using future builder, but it has lots of drawbacks , i was curious if i can manage it inside go router

Comment: There are no drawbacks. Take a look at the link I've shared, that's in the beginning of my answer. I think you need to learn how to use async functions. You'll need to know it, even if you think you don't need it.